# Find properties of relations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

Are any one of the below relations reflexive, symmetrical, anti-symmetrical or transitive?

a)
$$ X = P (\mathbb{Z}). \textrm{ARB if B}  \setminus A \textrm{ has only odd numbers and} A \subset B   $$

b) $$ \textrm{X is the set of all functions f} : \mathbb{R->R}.\textrm{ fSg if f-g is an even function} $$

c)
$$ \textrm{X is the set of all functions f} : \mathbb{R->Z}.\textrm{ fTg if f(1)|g(1)} $$

I do not understand the questions at all. Not what they mean or what they're asking.

a) What is the relation that the question is asking about? is it X or ARB? How are  properties like reflexivity expressed in this scenario since they are only defined for binary relations (and P(Z) is not binary?)?

b) what does fSg mean?

c) does | mean or in this context? what is fTg? Is it the same as ARB?

Comment: (a) The domain of the relation is $X$ which is here the powerset of $\Bbb Z$, the set of all subsets of integers.  The relation for (a) is the relation that one set of integers $A$ is related to another set of integers $B$ iff the difference $A\setminus B$ contains only odd integers and $A\subseteq B$.  Note that the empty set does not contain any even integers.  The relation here was named $R$ (*it could have been clearer about this*) and we write that $A$ is related to $B$ either as $(A,B)\in R$ or as $ARB$.

Comment: (b) The relation here was named $S$ (*again, they could have been clearer about this*).  As before, we write that $f$ is related to $g$ either as $(f,g)\in S$ or as $fSg$.  (c) The same, but here we have named the relation $T$.  In all questions, you are asked to prove why they are reflexive, symmetric, antisymmetric, or transitive relations and/or give counterexamples for why they are not.